# Convert string literals to unicode literals for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, unicode

I have an application that dynamically constructs SQL statements in about a million different places. Currently it works with SQL Server and all the character columns are `varchar`.

I now need to convert the application to support unicode with SQL Server. Unfortunately with SQL Server, it means I have to change all the DB columns to `nvarchar`, but that's ok.

The real problem is that I now have to change all the dynamic SQL creation to prepend `'N'` to every string literal, so that `select 'Hello'` becomes `select N'hello'`. That will take ages and is very error prone.

However, while SQL strings are created all over the place, they are only executed on the database in a few places. So I'm thinking about creating a function that takes a SQL string and prefixes all the string literals with `N`. If that works, it'll save a lot of development time.

Is this a viable approach? Has it been done before?

Comment: Theoretically, **Yes** it is viable , physically try it and tell us.

Comment: If your current code is not constructing SQL statements through a central place that takes care of things like safe string escaping, you are already doomed. The fact that you don't have such a place to add the `N'` for you is icing on the cake. Parsing SQL to weed out literals is just making the present mess messier. And unsafer. Centralize statement generation in a class, then you're free to change things. Heck, that would even allow you to start using parameters and avoid SQL injection problems altogether.

Comment: You shouldn't use dynamic sql like this. Here is article about dynamic SQL: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html . You should use parameters instead of literals